# Differences between roulette wheel selection and rank based selection

Tags: algorithm, selection, rank, genetic

> what are the differences between roulette wheel selection and rank based selection in genetic algorithm.

i am confused which one is best for me now. that's why just want to know the differences.

Answer (score 5):

The Rank Based Selection algorithm assigns probability(of them getting selected) to the items according to the priority they have. For example, the least priority item might get 10%, the one above that 20% and so on. In other words, the probability of an item getting selected is modified, and is determined by the algorithm.

But Roulette Wheel algorithm doesn't modify the probability of items. That is if an item has 99% probability, it will remain the same while making selection. But the problem here is, it reduces the chances of others getting selected to nil.

If you want to understand further, visit this [link](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/selection.php) .

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use different selection schemes. Change it dynamically.
The primitive heuristic method is: if the the best individual has >= p% probability (p=80..100, for example) then use rank selection for a while otherwise use the default roulette selection. I think that roulette selection is better for some primary evolution steps. When the stagnation is closer then switch to rank selection.